# Конфликт двух ImageButton

Tags: android, xml, imagebutton

Столкнулся с проблемой масштабирования ImageButton, при уменьшении экрана телефона нижняя кнопка начинает сужаться,а при увеличении экрана остаётся очень много пустого места,как сделать кнопки адаптируемыми под размер экрана используя при этом именно RelativeLayout, так как мне нужен небольшой эффект "наложения" объектов друг на друга
код xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fongame"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:context="com.jkey.transorgirl.Game">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotation="-2"
        android:background="@drawable/who" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt"
        android:id="@+id/imgbut"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="290dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:rotation="3" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgbut"
        android:id="@+id/imgbut2"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="290dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:rotation="-4" />

</RelativeLayout>
```